# List comprehension with Selenium elements in Python not working with tweets

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am scraping a Twitter page using Selenium and my scraped tweets are stored in a list variable `tweets`. I can iterate through them normally and extract the text from them using:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

However, when I try to use list comprehension and do

```
[tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
```

I get a `StaleElementReferenceException`

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of [object String] "b22c079f-684f-4d46-942b-d5dd69203728" is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `[tweet.text for tweet in tweets]` what action you are doing in this loop. Seems your DOM get reload. see description _it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed_

Comment: no action at all. the for loop works, the list comprehension doesn't.

Comment: @wrahool you probably updated/refreshed browser content in meantime

Answer (score 1):

The state of element has been changed when you are trying list comprehension. So get the tweets elements before list comprehension, like below.

```
tweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('YOUR_XPATH_HERE')
tweets_lists = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on how you attempt to construct the [list](/questions/tagged/list) **tweets**.

Ideally, to extract the texts from all of the *tweets* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector_of_tweets")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_tweets")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)